# Libsvm parameters (c, g, p) search

Tags: regression, matlab, libsvm

Is there a way to find the libsvm parameters (c, g, p) for REGRESSION  in MATLAB?
It's ok to find them with gridgregression.py but what if we want to use them in Matlab? It is a bit timespend to export the train x and y matrix and find the parameteres via gridregression.py.

Answer (score 0):

Write the cross-validation procedure manually. It's just 3 nested loops (over possible values of $c$, $g$ and $p$). In the inner loop you call `svm-train` in cross-validation mode (`-v k`) for k-fold cross-validation.

Save the best $(c,g,p)$-tuple you obtain and you are done.

Comment: I already use 'bestcv = 0;
for log2c = -1:6,
  for log2g = -8:0,
      for log2p = -8:-1,
        cmd = ['-v 5 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g), ' -p ', num2str(2^log2p)];
        cv = svmtrain(y, x, cmd);
        if (cv >= bestcv),
            bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g; bestp = 2^log2p;
        end
        fprintf('(best c=%g, g=%g, p=%g, rate=%g)\n',bestc, bestg, bestp, bestcv);
        break;
      end
  end
end`      HOWEVER it does not give the solution(MSE) well as gridregression.py

Comment: `bestcv = 0; 
for log2c = -1:6,
  for log2g = -8:0,
      for log2p = -8:-1,
        cmd = ['-v 5 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g), ' -p ', num2str(2^log2p)];
        cv = svmtrain(y, x, cmd);
        if (cv >= bestcv),
            bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g; bestp = 2^log2p;
        end
        fprintf('(best c=%g, g=%g, p=%g, rate=%g)\n',bestc, bestg, bestp, bestcv);
        break;
      end
  end
end`